# Sending a message from a Java Application to a listening Android App

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have a desktop application running which when a certain event happens, needs to send a message to any connected Android devices.

First, the user must have the application on their phone.

Second, the device the application is on must be authorized to receive these messages.

I was thinking that when the user starts the app on their phone, they should enter login details which are verified by the desktop app and is then registered to receive messages.

My problem is twofold

- **How can I send the login details to the desktop Application?**
- **How can I send a message from the desktop to the Android App?**

Also, what would the best method of contacting the mobile apps be without constantly having the application running / listening for a message from the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I send the login details to the desktop Application?

You can use TCP protocol for this problem.

> How can I send a message from the desktop to the Android App?

And for that, you can use [GoogleCloudMessaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)